# How Global.asax Works?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpapplication

in global.asax , how these events

```
   Application_Start
   Application_End
   Session_Start
   Session_End
   Application_BeginRequest
   Application_AuthenticateRequest
   Application_Error
```

hooked up to the corresponding eventhandler in System.Web.HttpApplication class

thanks !

Edit: maybe this is what i want [link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jun/18/How-do-ASPNET-Application-Events-Work)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to understand? You realise that the global.asax is of type `HttpApplication`.

Comment: why i can't find Application_start,Application_End .... in HttpApplication ?

Comment: or how can i understand "why application_start executed when Application Starts" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ASP.NET starts up your application, it creates an instance of your application's `HttpApplication` implementation, which is represented by Global.asax. It then uses reflection to look for methods named appropriately with the correct parameters, that match each of the events. Those it finds, it attaches as event handlers automatically for you.